# Is there a way to reverse-text-to-columns in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, textjoin

I have n columns and m rows of cells.

[image]

1. I want to batch concatenate each cell in a row into a **comma-separated** entry:

   > Topic 1, Topic 8, Topic 13, Topic n
2. Then, I want to batch concatenate each of these previously concatenated entries into one sequence of **semi-colon-separated** entries:

   > Topic 1, Topic 8, Topic 13, Topic n; Topic 2, Topic 9, Topic 10, Topic n;....
3. I would like for the output to be a conversion of all n-columns and m-rows into text in one single cell, with the above format.

It's basically a reverse-text-to-columns that reduces a table to a single cell. I have tried doing this with `CONCATENATE`, but it doesn't scale for n-columns/m-rows, and I can't seem to find a Macro solution. I would greatly appreciate any help in this matter!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your dataset is small you can use:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", "; 1; A:D)
```

if your dataset is huge you can do:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(A:D="",,A:D&",")),,999^99)),,999^99))
```

tho empty cells may introduce unwanted multi-spacing so to counter it do:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(A:D="",,"♦"&A:D&",")),,999^99)),,999^99), "♦"))),,999^99))
```

---

### UPDATE:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(QUERY(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(A3:D="",, A3:D&",")),,999^99))&";"), ", ;|,;", ";"),
 "where not Col1 starts with ';'", 0),,999^99))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks for your response. The text-joined rows are comma-separated,  but the combined-entries are not semi-colon separated. I want to distinguish between the two, and haven't found a way. It's important that the combined-entries be separated by semi-colons in order to distinguish between the rows, and your answers don't provide for the shift from comma-separated to semi-colon separated batches

Comment: This latest update works well with comma to semi-colon batching, but I'm noticing extra commas at the end of some batches, adjacent to semi-colons: Topic 1, Topic 8, Topic 13, Topic n,; Topic 2, Topic 9, Topic 10, Topic n,;         Do you have an idea why this is happening?

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N16qRkBdQbMyiinpUGBd6JNGxLRPQ-Nn587wa7edSPs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: fixed. last formula in answer and your sheet updated